# Android resizing SeekBar thumb width from maximum value

Tags: java, android, xml, seekbar

Is there a function (or an XML tag) which allows to change the width of thumb in the seekBar dynamically , when the maxValue is changed . For example if the maxValue == 2 the Thumb takes the half of the whole Seekbar , then if maxValue is 3 , it takes the 1/3-th of the width , and so on .

Answer (score 0):

The SeekBar thumb can only be set in XML, not dynamically. What you are looking for is akin to a scrollbar. Views which are scrollable, like ListView, have these built in, so you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Iam using SeekBar for scrolling the `HorizontalScrollView` . Is there a way to set the scrollbar separately from scrollView ?

Comment: As far as I know, the HorizontalScrollView has its own scrollbars. Why are you trying to duplicate this functionality by adding a SeekBar?

Comment: is there a margin for scrollbar , I dont want it to take all the width of the scrollView ? or can I change the design of the scrollbar ?

Comment: You can influence the look and feel of the scrollbar using themes and styles.

Answer (score 0):

You need to programatically implement the logic..by using thumsize and progress values and implementing OnSeekBarChangeListener

You can ask if you have any further queries :)

Comment: how can I change the size of the thumb programatically ?

Comment: @user3199577 :use seekbar.setThumbOffset(int pixels);

Comment: Something changed , and I dont understand what exactly . But I didn't get what I wanted :)

Comment: I suggest you to create custom seek bar instead

Comment: setThumbOffset sets how much of the thumb can go off the end of the track - it assumes you have a symmetrical thumb drawable, but if you don't you can line up your drawable & track

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting only android devices running v16+, you might be able to do this using `getThumb().setBounds()`, but doing so may have consequences if you do it whilst the user is touching the view.

You will also want to update the offset using `setThumbOffset()` passing in 1/2 the width of the new bounds.

You can also just replace the thumb with a new drawable, which will update the offset for you (if you have a symmetrical drawable), but adjust its bounds is probably going to be more efficient.