# Unable to resize the thumb of Seekbar android

Tags: android, seekbar, android-5.1.1-lollipop, seekbar-thumb

I have tried different ways to resize the thumb size of `Seekbar` but got no success.
This is the thumb of my `Seekbar` with pressed effect too:

[image]
[image]
My thumb selector file where I have added these two images to get press effect:
lessons_thumb_selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lessons_thumb" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lessons_pressed"/>
</selector>
```

And my thumb file where I have resized the thumb selector:
thumb_drawable_lessons.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/lessons_thumb_selector"
        android:width="50dp"
        android:height="50dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

And my `Seekbar` tag in layout file where I have used the Seekbar with this thumb is:

```
    <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/sBarLessons"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/styledprogrees"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_drawable_lessons"
    style="@style/book_categories_seekbar_style"
    />
```

And style tag in style.xml file is this:
     
            430dp
            175dp
            @color/transparent
            100
            10dp
            false
        
And the problem is! everything looks fine when I see in Android Studio layout preview:
[image]

But when i execute and install apk on device it shows thumb size the same and dislocated from `Seekbar`:
[image]
Note: 
 - Press effect is working fine.
 
 - Using the same image for 10 inch device and trying to resize it for 7 inch device.
 - Please note aligning is not an issue, issue is resizing. I want to reduce the size of thumb proportionately.
 - Also generating 9-patch doesn't help in my solution.
 - Using Lolipop 5.1.1 version in my devices.

I have tried these solutions too but got no success:
[Android SeekBar thumb gets clipped/cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912609/android-seekbar-thumb-gets-clipped-cut-off)
[dynamically resized Thumb of SeekBar gets clipped above and below, how to draw on top (Z order)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802231/dynamically-resized-thumb-of-seekbar-gets-clipped-above-and-below-how-to-draw-o)
[Android resizing SeekBar thumb width from maximum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401884/android-resizing-seekbar-thumb-width-from-maximum-value)

Comment: try  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150340/align-android-seekbar-with-thumb

Comment: aligning is not the issue, want to resize thumb! @AmolDesai

Comment: Try with android:minWidth and android:minHeight to resize it, give me word if it works.

Comment: tried that too! but it didn't get effect. @MyWay

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem a few days ago. I was trying to style a Switch widget and its thumb was awful (like yours). But original works without any problem. I opened original drawables and found they are 9-patch.

So I converted my images to 9-patch and problem was solved.

This is a thumb (left) and track (right) opened in a Android Studio 9-patch editor (note the markup)

[image: This is a thumb and track]

Comment: It looks like I didn't understand question. You are trying to dynamically resize thumb depending on screen size ?

Comment: yes I want to resize seekbar thumb images from dimens according to device resolution, i have these images for 720 dpi want to resize it for 600 dpi from dimens

Comment: Did you try to resize it programmatically and then setThumb() ?

Comment: tried to getThumb() and set bounds but no success in that too! and there is no method for setting width and height for drawable!

Comment: not working! resizing bitmap only works but resizing bitmapDrawable doesn't work! if I resize single bitmap then press effect can not work on seekbar thumb!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501716/android-how-to-create-a-statelistdrawable-programmatically#